# Failed to start Greengrass Daemon in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to set up AWS IoT Greengrass in my virtual machine Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

I followed the steps here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/install-ggc.html

In these 2 commands `systemctl start greengrass.service` and `systemctl status greengrass.service`, I receive this error: `Failed to start Greengrass Daemon.`

```
VirtualBox@VirtualBox:~/Downloads/folder1$ systemctl status greengrass.service
● greengrass.service - Greengrass Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/greengrass.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-11-18 10:31:15 CET; 13min ago
    Process: 5420 ExecStart=/greengrass/ggc/core/greengrassd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 18 10:31:15 VirtualBox systemd[1]: greengrass.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is>
Nov 18 10:31:15 VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped Greengrass Daemon.
Nov 18 10:31:15 VirtualBox systemd[1]: greengrass.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 18 10:31:15 VirtualBox systemd[1]: greengrass.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 18 10:31:15 VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start Greengrass Daemon.

VirtualBox@VirtualBox:~/Downloads/folder1$ systemctl start greengrass.service
Job for greengrass.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status greengrass.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Do you have any idea about what can be the problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

```
$ cd /greengrass/certs/
$ sudo wget -O root.ca.pem https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it